# Typescript error "Angular has no exported member 'route'"

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript

I am trying to use Typescript definitions for the latest Angular and Angular-Route from [DefinitelyType](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/) for Angular 1.7.8.

I prefer Angular 1 over 2.

I am attempting to setup TypeScript in Visual Studio 2019 without any module loaders or package managers etc. I've just added the .d.ts files into /scripts/typings.

I have 2 files, app.module.ts and app.route.ts. The app.module.ts has no errors and generates a js file.

My app.route.ts file looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/angular/angular-route.d.ts" />

module MyApplication
{
"use strict";

function routes($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider)
{
    $routeProvider
       .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "/scripts/app/home/home.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/home"
        });
}

routes.$inject = ["$routeProvider"]

angular
    .module("MyApplication")
    .config(routes);
```

}

But I see this error and no app.route.js file is generated:

```
 Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'route'.
```

Because I'm not using an module loader, i have to comment out this line in angular-route.d.ts:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

So I'm not sure if this is breaking anything.

Why is ng.route not resolving and giving an error?

Also wouldn't mind comments if my app.route.ts file is actually implemented using TypeScript and not just regular Javascript (i know js = ts but maybe with ts it can be/should be different).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the importing of angular in the route definitions, there is no angular to put the route definitions into, I suppose.

I'm not sure if the setup you describe is possible. Even if it is, you will surely find plenty of problems like this. Setting up a simple Webpack environment with Angular 1 and Typescript would be much easier.